# Imported functions are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I am using Webpack via Vue CLI and am getting a `Error in created hook: "TypeError: _api__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.$_playerApi_getPlayers is not a function"` error when I try to use my page.

Here is my tree structure:

```
.
+ main.js
+ app/
|  + api.js
|  + App.vue
|  + players/
|  |  + api.js
|  |  + index.js
|  |  + routes.js
|  |  + components/
|  |  |  + index.js
|  |  |  + Login.vue
|  |  |
|  |  + vuex/
|  |     + actions.js
|  |     + ...
|  |
|  + others/
|     + api.js
|     + ...
|
+ ...
```

*app/players/vuex/actions.js*:

```
import { default as api } from '../../api'

export default {

  loadPlayers({ commit }) {
    return api.$_playerApi_getPlayers().then(response => {  // <--- ERROR LINE
      commit('STORE_PLAYERS', response.body)
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error
    })
  },

  loadPlayer({ commit }, playerId) {
    return api.$_playerApi_getPlayer(playerId).then(response => {
      commit('LOAD_PLAYER', response.data)
      return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error
    })
  },

  ...

}
```

*app/players/api.js*:

```
export default {

  ...

  $_playerApi_getPlayer(playerId = '') {
    ...
  },

  $_playerApi_getPlayers() {
    ...
  },

  ...

}
```

*app/api.js*:

```
import { api as players } from './players'

export default {
  players,
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is wrong (obv.) but am not sure how to get it to work properly.

What am I doing wrong here? The exports and imports seem OK, but they're breaking somehow that I just can't see or debug.

I've tried using the following in my *app/api.js* but this is wrong because the export is not an array:

```
import { api as players } from './players'

export default {
  ...players,
}
```

I've also tried using the following in my *app/players/api.js* but it didn't work, either:

```
export default {

  methods: {

    ...

    $_playerApi_getPlayer(playerId = '') {
      ...
    },

    $_playerApi_getPlayers() {
      ...
    },

    ...

  },

}
```

Comment: Can you post the created hook code from where the error is raised?

Comment: `* as players` did you try this?

Comment: in your `app/app.js`, why not `import api as players from './players'` ? without `{}`

Comment: @wrufesh the location that it's giving as the error location is the indicated line in *app/players/vuex/actions.js*

Comment: @wrufesh The created hook is just calling `this.loadPlayers()...` that was mapped via `...mapActions`

Comment: Please post your players/index.js

Answer (score 1):

In your `app/api.js`:

```
import * as players from './players/api'
export default {
  ...players,
}
```

and in your `app/players/api.js`:

```
export function $_playerApi_getPlayer(playerId = '') {
   ...
}

export function $_playerApi_getPlayers() {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This did not work. I still get the same error as above.

Comment: This did work if I changed *app/api.js* to export with `...players`.

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary in some cases?